# Question about the spin of the antiparticle of $Δ^-$

Tags: quantum-spin, standard-model, antimatter, baryons

Ι came across a statement in a physics book that the spin of the antiparticle of baryon $Δ^-$ is 1/2. I know that the spin for regular $Δ^-$ is 3/2, and - as far as I know - the spin of particles and anti-particles should match.

Is this a mistake in the book?

Comment: Have you identified the mass of the state? $\Delta$ is a collective term for isoquartets, and the PDG mentions a 1620 and a 1910 that are spin 1/2... Can you be more explicit and precise about the "book" and the usage of the point?

Answer (score 1):

The spin of the $\bar\Delta^-$ baryon (the antiparticle of the $\Delta^-$ baryon) is -3/2, however the book *may* be referring to the $\Delta^+$ baryon, which has spin +1/2.